# Hammack set-builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\left \{  \bigcup_{X\in Powerset{(N)}}X \right \}= \mathbb{N} $

(Union of the sets X)

The Hammack Book of Proof says the answer is $\mathbb{N}$

But shouldn't it be $\varnothing $ + $\mathbb{N}$ ?  I believe this because $\varnothing $ is a member of any powerset.  and here X is all those members (including $\varnothing $)

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Following the idea of the answer of Noah, by the other hand, we have that $\emptyset\subset A$ for any set $A$. But, IMO, the result of $\{\bigcup_{X\in\mathcal P(\Bbb N)} X\}=\{\Bbb N\}$ instead of just $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @Masacroso  This textbook I'm using would say {N} != N.  First is "set containing the set of natural numbers"  and the second is "the set of natural numbers"

Comment: Yes, $\{\Bbb N\}\neq\Bbb N$. But what I said is that for the standard notation, I dont know if it is the same of your book, the result of your question should be $\{\Bbb N\}$ instead of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Yeah, the Hammack books just gives the answer as N  not {N}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\emptyset \cup\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{N}$. In general, $\emptyset\cup A=A$ for any set $A$.

For a concrete example, consider $\{0, 1\}$. Then $$\bigcup_{X\in Powerset(\{0, 1\})}X=\emptyset\cup\{0\}\cup\{1\}\cup\{0, 1\}=\{0, 1\}.$$ Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Def'n: $\cup F=\{x: \exists f\in F\;(x\in f)\}.$

Def'n: $\cup_{f\in F}f=\cup F.$

Therefore $x\in \cup_{P(A)}f\iff x\in \cup P( A\}\iff \exists f\in P(A)\;(x\in f) \iff x\in A.$

Comment: Trying to interpret your first line, "definition of the union of set F equals the set where for each member, x,  there exists a ?something? f, which is a member of F .... and then from here I do not understand the notation."  Could you give an English language description of the first line of the definition?

Comment: $x$ belongs to $\cup F$ iff $x$ belongs to some member  $(f)$ of $F.$ So $\cup F$ is the set of the members of the members of $F$.